# PHP's preg_replace in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How do I do a preg_replace in Javascript?

I do the following in PHP, but would like to move it to Javascript.

```
<?php

$errors  = '::Could not sign you into your account! ';
$errors .= '::Email or password error! ';

$errors = preg_replace('#\::(.+?)(?![^::])#','<div>$1</div>',$errors);

echo ($errors);

?>
```

[Fiddle](https://eval.in/512901)

I tried doing the same using JavaScript, but it just will not work somehow. Any thoughts on how this can be done?

```
var theString = "::Could not sign you into your account! :: Email or Password Error! ";

theString = theString.replace('#\::(.+?)(?![^::])#/g','<div>$1</div>');

alert(theString);
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6df3uyw/1/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace has some useful info to guide you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript regexps mostly do not use quotes and `#`:

```
var theString = "::Could not sign you into your account! :: Email or Password Error! ";
theString = theString.replace(/\::(.+?)(?![^::])/g,'<div>$1</div>');
alert(theString);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rhtfzmxd/